# PUT/GET with Payload using Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using Restangular in one of my works

The server guys have give me the following calls which i need to integrate on the AngularJS client

1. PUT api/partners/password – RequestPayload[{password,confirmpassword}]
   partner id is being sent in the header
2. GET api/partners/password/forgot/ - Request Payload [{emailaddress}]
   partner id is being sent in the header

The javascript code that I have written to call these services is as follow

1. Restangular.all('Partners').one('Password').put(params); - sends params as query string
2. Restangular.all('Partners').one('Password').one('Forgot').get(params); - sends object in the url

I have tried other ways but it simply doesn't make the correct call.

Help me out guys!

Comment: Can you show what you mean by "doesn't make the correct call". Maybe post the error you're seeing in your browser debug tool?

Comment: there is no error, by incorrect call I mean that for #1 I am trying to send params as request payload and it is sending by query string, similar for #2

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So, for point #1. it puts the object at hand, not another object. So you have 2 options:

Option 1

```
var passReq = Restangular.all('Partners').one('Password');
passReq.confirmPassword = ....
passReq.put(); // confirmPassword and the params of the object will be sent
```

Option 2 is

```
var passReq = Restangular.all('Partners').one('Password').customPUT(obj);
```

For Point #2, you cannot send a request body (payload) in the GET unfortunately.

Comment: alright .. i m not on my work machine now, and its weekend here. Ill accept the answer once I test it on monday :)

Comment: Why does the patch function accept an object and not the put function. It seems a bit inconsistent.